# How to deal with lack of peers?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am pursuing a B.S in Mathematics(freshman) in a country where people rarely study math for the sake of it and in a new university with good professors. Yet, it is new and I suffer from the lack of peers and it is literally impossible to pick up mathematical conversations on ideas with students . As a result, I find it difficult to exchange ideas with others.

Is there something which can be done to make sure that lack of peers or the pressure to push oneself doesn't harm me much?

Comment: If you're truly passionate about the subject, then simply reminding yourself why you're passionate should be enough. Pressure from exams helps too. If you want conversation, the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) here might be a place to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I struggled during many of my years as a student, for much the same reason, and that's even living in the U.S.! (That may also be due to the fact that during most of my years from secondary school on, I was the only "girl" in classes of all "boys", so I have found it very difficult to "talk math" with my girl friends.) It has felt lonely at times!

But there's a wide world out there awaiting you. Sites like math.stackexchange.com, and its [chatrooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), helps to fill in the gaps. There are also other online forums. I'd encourage you to obtain membership(s) to Professional organizations, e.g. [AMS](http://www.ams.org/home/page), where there are [webpages designed specifically for students](http://www.ams.org/profession/student), including forums. You can also join, for example in the [MAA](http://www.maa.org/), special interest groups when you're a member ([SIGMAA's](http://www.maa.org/community/sigmaas)).

Soon, you will "grow into" a larger accepting group of "mathies" as you get to know your professors, find a mentor (and do find a mentor!), and progress in your studies. It will happen, and there's many more students like yourself than may appear at first glance! Find them (locally or internationally!), take the lead if you need to (you can form student chapters aligned with professional organizations, e.g.), ask your professors if there are any conferences which you can attend, even if just to listen, and mingle a bit. Let your passion and enthusiasm for math show: it can be contagious!

Comment: Excellent advice and encouragement! +1